# Grunt template variables and if else

Tags: javascript, variables, if-statement, gruntjs

I have some template variables in my Gruntfile for my dist folders. I also want to use them in an if else statement to adjust the configuration of some tasks.

Here a short version of my Gruntfile:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({

        // Variables
        path: {
            develop: 'dev/',
            output: 'output/'
        },

        // Clean empty task
        cleanempty: {
            output: {
                src: '<%= path.output %>**/*'
            }
        },

        // Sync
        sync: {
            output: (function(){
                console.log(grunt.config('path.output'));  // Returns undefined

                if(grunt.config('path.output') === 'output/') {
                    return {
                        // Config A
                    }

                } else {
                    return {
                        // Config B
                    }
                }
            }())
        }
```

unfortunately I cant get it work. grunt.config('path.output') returns undefined.
How can I read Grunt template variables? Tips for a way better solution, I also like to hear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables need to be declared outside grunt.initConfig. Then you need to refer to it within grunt.initConfig

Found my solution at:
http://chrisawren.com/posts/Advanced-Grunt-tooling

Working sample:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    // Variables
    var path = {
        develop: 'dev/',
        output: 'output/'
    };

    grunt.initConfig({
        path: path, // <-- Important part, do not forget


        // Clean empty task
        cleanempty: {
            output: {
                src: '<%= path.output %>**/*'
            }
        },

        // Sync
        sync: {
            output: (function(){
                console.log(path.output);  // Returns output/

                if(path.output) === 'output/') {
                    return {
                        // Config A
                    }

                } else {
                    return {
                        // Config B
                    }
                }
            }())
        }
        //...the rest of init config
     });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
grunt.config.get('path.output')
```

Comment: Thanks, but still returns undefinded.